# Debian PowerPC Linux installation on IBM IntelliStation POWER 285 9111 fails on yaboot

Tags: linux, grub, powerpc, debian-installer

I'm trying to install Debian Wheezy here.
I have two hard drives. One is running AIX well. I'm trying to get Linux to run from the other one.

The installer boots fine. Automatic partition creates a ˜7MB PReP boot partition, all goes well. But later on, yaboot configuration fails insisting that it needs an Apple_Bootstrap partition.

Then I have two options: I can install GRUB or install the kernel in a PReP boot partition. GRUB installs, but the broken yaboot configuration is there. So when I boot, I'm stuck in the yaboot console.

I tried the expert installation mode, skipping the yaboot installation. But I don't know the partitioning requirements for GRUB on my platform. I tried it once, and it fails as well. I get a message also informing me the support is experimental.

After lots of googling, it seems that this is/was a bug in yaboot, that was resolved years ago.

Any suggestions? Or ideas from anyone running Debian on pSeries or other similar boxes?

Comment: You can use : https://lists.debian.org/debian-powerpc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it up.

When I was going around and try to boot from the Open Firmware, it would load yaboot and start to load the kernel, but then get stuck waiting for the root filesystem. This was resolved by separating /boot in an ext2 partition.

But I would still not manage to get yaboot (or GRUB) properly configured during the installation. More digging into the Open Firmware showed me something interesting:

The *devalias* for **disk** was my SECOND disk (SCSI ID 8), not the first one (SCSI ID 5). I was trying to install Debian to the first disk, but all yaboot configuration was being built based on that *devalias*.

I don't have much patience to struggle with Open Firmware, so I just moved my AIX installation to the first disk **(0,5,0)** and installed Linux to the second one **(0,8,0)**. I enabled the Multi Boot option in the Open Firmware menu so I get asked from what disk I want to boot every time I turn my workstation on.

The successful installation partition table is the following:

1. PowerPC PreP boot partition (8MB)
2. */boot* mount point (300MB - ext2)
3. */* mount point (the rest) I tested this one with ext2, but I believe it would work with ext4 just fine.
4. *swap*

Maybe I would not have had issues with the *devalias* if I would have upgraded my firmware. I bought this workstation new a few months ago, and it was boxed at the reseller for ages and has a very old firmware version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while back ([Boot to non bootable disk using Openfirmware](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192196/boot-to-non-bootable-disk-using-openfirmware)) and I got around it by booting into the hard disk using install media's rescue mode and installing grub-ieee1275 from the official repos the normal way.

Comment: grub-ieee1275 in rescue mode didn't help me. But the idea of using rescue mode to do changes and tests instead of reinstalling everything all the time was a great idea - the kind of thing I wonder why I was not doing before.