# Boot to non bootable disk using Openfirmware

Tags: debian, aix, virtualization, powerpc

I tried to virtualize (VIOS partition) Debian 7.8 on IBM 9133-55A (powerpc) server. For some reason both yaboot and grub failed to install on the virtual hard disk. Now I want to start the kernel directly from the openfirmware prompt but I cant find the virtual hard disk on the prompt. Here is the output of the ls command. (http://pastebin.com/9cbHQA93)

When I boot the VM using debian installation media hard disk is /dev/sda and root partition is /dev/sda2

Answer (score 0):

It seems like openfirmware IBM uses have a problem with ext4 partitions. For some reason disks are not available in the of device tree but they are accessible on /vdevice/v-scsi@/disk@.

I got around the grub not installing problem by booting the installation disk in rescue mode chrooting into installed system, uninstalling default grub and installing grub-ieee1275 on the PReP Boot partition.